# Why can't I open some .ann files by `pandas.read_csv()`?

Tags: python, pandas, annotations, glob

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path


Drugs = ['ARTHROTEC', 'CAMBIA', 'CATAFLAM', 'DICLOFENAC-POTASSIUM', 'DICLOFENAC-SODIUM',
         'FLECTOR', 'LIPITOR', 'PENNSAID', 'SOLARAZE', 'VOLTAREN', 'VOLTAREN-XR', 'ZIPSOR']
def extract_Tags(drug):
    Files = Path('E:/TM/Final/CADEC/original').glob(drug+'*.ann')
    for file in Files:
        try:
            data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None)
        except:
            print('Cannot open ', file)
    print(drug, '\n')
```

I have a lot of `.ann` files under a directory, each title starting with a drug name. I tried to read in data from them by `pandas.read_csv()`. However, some files can be opened and other not. I got what I got, and I don't know how to check what goes wrong with those unopenable files. Should I use other command to open them?

```
for drug in Drugs:
    extract_Tags(drug)

ARTHROTEC 

Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\CAMBIA.1.ann
CAMBIA 

CATAFLAM 

DICLOFENAC-POTASSIUM 

DICLOFENAC-SODIUM 

FLECTOR 

Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\LIPITOR.197.ann
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\LIPITOR.243.ann
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\LIPITOR.28.ann
...
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\LIPITOR.964.ann
LIPITOR 

Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\PENNSAID.2.ann
PENNSAID 

Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\SOLARAZE.1.ann
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\SOLARAZE.3.ann
SOLARAZE 

Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\VOLTAREN-XR.11.ann
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\VOLTAREN-XR.13.ann
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\VOLTAREN-XR.4.ann
...
VOLTAREN 

Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\VOLTAREN-XR.11.ann
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\VOLTAREN-XR.13.ann
Cannot open  E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\VOLTAREN-XR.4.ann
...
VOLTAREN-XR 

ZIPSOR
```

And if I try to open one of those files in specific, it returns **"No columns to parse from file"**, which I don't really understand. How can I find out whether the data files are broken or I should do things some other way? BTW, because this is kinda a benchmark dataset, I find it perculiar to have files ill-constructed.

```py
pd.read_csv("E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\LIPITOR.197.ann", sep='\t', header=None)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EmptyDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8f6a7735c992> in <module>
      1 # check one of the unopenable files
----> 2 pd.read_csv("E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\LIPITOR.197.ann", sep='\t', header=None)

d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446 
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449 
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879 
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881 
    882     def close(self):

d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: Unless we have a crystal ball it s a bit tricky to guess what could it be. Maybe you should try to handle the exceptions better & actually read what's wrong with those individual files? Try using `except Exception as err: ` and then simply print that `err` do see what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did add the error information for opening one problematic file in specific. Still, I don't understand it though.

Comment: `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`
Suggests that there is no data in this file. could you post a bit of the file for us to look at?

Comment: @PaulBrennan I do want to, but I don't know how since I can't open it. Sorry I'm a total newbie.

Comment: open `E:\TM\Final\CADEC\original\LIPITOR.197.ann` in notepad and just copy the top 5 lines and put them in a data section in the question.

Comment: @PaulBrennan Thank you very much! Now I open them with Notepad++, I can see the data are indeed incomplete!